# Cant find nodejs on Debian

Tags: debian, nodejs, npm

I install nodejs  to Debian. But I cant find it in /usr/bin/nodejs. I try to search but have the same result.

> nodejs -v
>
> v0.10.35

Where I can find nodejs file ?

Comment: I'm afraid Debian isn't quite on topic, even though Ubuntu is indeed Debian based... Unix & Linux should be more than happy to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

node shoud be located in: /usr/local/bin/node

node -v shows the version, to actually search for the file you need to

```
whereis node
```